# Bootstrap Gutter form with Vertical rows in same form

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a project that will ask users for their details and then underneath a bunch of questions. The details section uses a form with gutters (unsure if that is correct terminology). But i want to be able to input the questions and have them come down 1 by 1 in order. And not by the side of eachother like it does for inputting the details.

This is the link i used for the gutters- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/layout/

This is the link to what the details page looks like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYjjc.jpg

And i want it the questions like this underneath - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnksa.jpg

However they must be in the same form otherwise my code wont work and unsure to change it to submit the form from two pages...

Code of both parts - https://pastebin.com/5nbavuUt

```html
/* Code From Details */
 
<div class="col-md-7">
                    <label for="site_name" class="form-label">Site Name</label>
                    <input type="name" 
                           class="form-control" 
                           id="site_name" 
                           name="site_name" 
                           value="<?php if(isset($_GET['site_name']))
                                       echo ($_GET['site_name']); ?>"
                           placeholder="Enter Site Name"
                           required><br>
                </div>
 
/*Code From Questions */
<div class="form-group">
                <h6 for="q9">9. Is there clear access to the position of the Machine(s)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp(e.g. acess through doors)</h6>
                    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q9">
                        <option selected>Choose</option>
                        <option value="YES">Yes</option>
                        <option value="NO">No</option>
                    </select>
</div>
```